# How to only get data of first table on a Wikipedia page using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, wikipedia

I am trying to scrape data from a Wikipedia page.

**Page URL: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015_in_hip_hop_music**

This is the code I've currently come up with.

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
def make_soup(url):
    thepage=urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soupdata=BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
    return soupdata

soup= make_soup("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015_in_hip_hop_music")
albumdatasaved=""
for record in soup.findAll('tr'):
    albumdata=""
    for data in record.findAll('td'):
        albumdata=albumdata+","+data.text
    albumdatasaved=albumdatasaved+"\n"+albumdata[1:]

print(albumdatasaved)
```

However, my code gives the data of all 4 tables on the page.
Is there any way I can get the data of just the first one? (Released Albums)

Any help would be well appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
def make_soup(url):
    thepage=urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soupdata=BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
    return soupdata

soup= make_soup("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015_in_hip_hop_music")
albumdatasaved=""
# find all table ,get the first
table = soup.find_all('table', class_="wikitable")[0]  # Only use the first table
# iter over it
for record in table.findAll('tr'):
    albumdata=""
    for data in record.findAll('td'):
        albumdata=albumdata+","+data.text
    albumdatasaved=albumdatasaved+"\n"+albumdata[1:]

print(albumdatasaved)
```

Comment: How can I get table header with the data.

Comment: @RanchiRhino post another question and tagged with `beautifulsoup` and i will answer you there.

Comment: thanks, got it added headers in the `albumdatasaved` while creating it.